# Search letters in a specific position in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a column with  a Strig and i need search the rows that have  letters at the specific position.

For example . the user search :

011111Z
The letter are at the SEVEN (7) position.

The sql statement must search all the rows that have A-Z in the SEVEN (7) POSITION.

The output will be :

limit_superior:
000001A
/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]/

another one:
001AA

Must search  A-Z rows at the position 3,4 in the string row.

How can i generate a correct Sql statement in MYSQL.

[image]

Comment: You don't say which SQL you are using - DB2, MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL, ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using a regular expression, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^..[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]';
```